# Image storage in chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, base64, local-storage

I'm working on a chrome extension for which I'm fetching image from an api. I'm storing that image in the chrome local storage using the url directly like

`localStorage.setItem('image_url', "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1461456523134-43960ad9fce2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&s=cd4b561a5816f51c992f7965bbc6b011");`

It's working perfectly fine. Like it fetches images instantly from the local storage. But I have read in many stackoverflow solution is to first convert the image to base64 format and then save it in the form of data_url. I wanna know what's the con in the approach I'm following? And what's the difference between the approaches? 
And what would be the right approach to follow?

Comment: One is saving the URL - that means the image will be fetched again if not in cache. The other is saving a large chunk of image data in localStorage - if the image is small, no problem. That said, this question is off topic at SO as **Primarily opinion based** _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: You only set an image path to your local storage, so when that path won't exist anymore, the image won't exist as well.
If you save it in base64 and decode it in your website, the actual image is stored on the device, not the path to it. Hope it helps clear up :)

Comment: Base64 will be the solution, but the only inconvenient is probably speed. Images in base64 are generally slower to load than Normal images. But believe me, it works 

Comment: @StanGeorge Thanks for the response. So if it is setting an image path how come it gets loaded in less than 1 sec as if it being stored in the local storage?

Comment: Thanks @ArthurGuiot I will try out with base64 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response @mplungjan

Comment: Don't use base64 to store an image. If you really need to have this image stored in browser, then either use serviceWorkers or IndexedDB, which both can store Blobs (binary data).

Comment: FWIW you can also use Chrome-only [HTML5 FileSystem API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Comment: @wOxxOm Actually, the sandboxed filesystem api will be removed. See https://crbug.com/695508